# Sudden increase in traffic from Google search domains

Tags: google, google-analytics, search-engines, traffic

I'm suddenly getting a 50% increase in traffic.

The cause of this, according to my google analytics,  is referral traffic from sites such as:

```
google.co.uk
google.com.my
google.co.jp
google.com.sg
```

etc etc, none of which gave me traffic before.

Why am I suddenly getting traffic from these places?

Comment: You are ranking better in these search engines?

Comment: Cheers, you're achieving something everyone wants, you're being indexed! Now you have to worry about your server being able to handle the traffic.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, well done, you have obviously done something right.

As w3d has commented, this feels like you are ranking higher for certain search terms, in Google Analytics you can drill down to find out what terms are sending you the most traffic by going `TRAFFIC SOURCES > Sources > Search > Organic`, use the date range on the top right to compare last months to this months to see what could have contributed.

Answer (score 2):

The ranking of your site has improved in these countries. A reason could be that you gained some links from sites which are hosted in these countries. You could maybe check the backlinks of your site, maybe you will find the reason why the ranking of your site has improved there. Sometimes a blog article or a thread in a forum where your site has been linked can be enough for such an effect.

Answer (score 1):

Google has just [updated its search engine](http://insidesearch.blogspot.com/2011/11/ten-recent-algorithm-changes.html) in order to provide better results and remove low value websites.
I guess the result is that all the crap that was hiding your website is gone !